# Use font replacement for icons on my phpbb forum

Tags: fonts, icons, webfonts, phpbb

I apologize this is a very amateurish question.

I'm not very good at this stuff, so pardon me for my ignorance on this stuff.  I've been learning as I go and have done pretty good considering I had zero css or html knowledge 4 months ago.

My site is raider-forums.com, and I'd like to update the look with font replacement for my icons, which I think give a much cleaner look, especially with pinch and zoom.

I found icomoon which seems great for my needs, and I downloaded the zip file, but really am unsure how I would proceed.

I just need to know how I would change one of these, and I can copy it into the rest. For example on my sidebar menu (using helion style by artodia).

Here are the buttons I'd like to try and change from images to web font:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-section"><p>Sample Links</p></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Normal Link</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-forum"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-pm"><a href="#">Private Message</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-ucp"><a href="#">User Control Panel</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-users"><a href="#">Users List</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-search"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-down"><a href="#">Down Arrow</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

from common.css :

```
/*
   Menu
*/
.phpbb ul.menu {
   padding-bottom: 4px;
   margin: -1px 0 0;
}
.phpbb ul.menu-nopadding {
   padding-bottom: 0;
}
.phpbb ul.menu-nopadding + ul.menu {
   margin-top: 0;
}
.phpbb .menu > li {
   width: 200px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-form {
   padding: 2px;
   width: 196px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section {
   display: block;
   background: transparent none 0 -30px no-repeat;
   width: 190px;
   margin: 0 0 2px;
   padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.phpbb .menu li.menu-item a, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section a, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section p {
   display: block;
   background: transparent none 100% 0 no-repeat;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
   height: 22px;
   text-align: left;
   text-indent: 10px;
   line-height: 1.2em;
   white-space: nowrap;
   max-width: 180px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   outline-style: none;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-section.expandable a {
   max-width: 160px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 20px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-section {
   background-position: 0 0;
}

.phpbb .menu li.menu-section a, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section p {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: 600;
   background-position: 100% -30px;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 6px;
   height: 23px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-section a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.phpbb .menu li.menu-home {
   background-position: 0 -60px;
   padding-left: 27px;
   width: 173px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-forum {
   background-position: 0 -90px;
   padding-left: 27px;
   width: 173px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-pm {
   background-position: 0 -120px;
   padding-left: 28px;
   width: 172px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-ucp {
   background-position: 0 -150px;
   padding-left: 29px;
   width: 171px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-down {
   background-position: 0 -180px;
   padding-left: 27px;
   width: 173px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-login {
   background-position: 0 -210px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   width: 170px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-search {
   background-position: 0 -240px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   width: 170px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-users {
   background-position: 0 -270px;
   padding-left: 28px;
   width: 172px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-faq {
   background-position: 0 -300px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-link {
   background-position: 0 -330px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}
.phpbb .menu li.icon-thanks {
   background-position: 0 -360px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}

.phpbb .menu li.icon-points {
   background-position: 0 -390px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}

.phpbb .menu li.icon-quiz {
   background-position: 0 -450px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}

.phpbb .menu li.icon-arcade {
   background-position: 0 -480px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}

.phpbb .menu li.icon-bump {
   background-position: 0 -420px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   width: 175px;
}
```

and colours.css:

```
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section {
   background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/menu_left.png");
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item a, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section a, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section p, .phpbb li.menu-form input.button-icon {
   background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/menu_right.png");
}

.phpbb .menu li.menu-item {
   background-color: #393939;
   border-style: outset;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: #999999;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item:hover {
   background-color: #181818;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item.active {
   background-color: #565656;
   border-style: inset;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: #aaaaaa;
   color: #bbb !important;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-section, .phpbb li.menu-form input.button-icon {
   background-color: #181818;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-section:hover, .phpbb li.menu-form input.button-icon:hover {
   background-color: #181818;
}

.phpbb .menu li.menu-item a {
   color: #dddddd;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item:hover a {
   color: #555555;
}
.phpbb .menu li.menu-item.active a {
   color: #bbb;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.phpbb .menu li.menu-section p, .phpbb .menu li.menu-section a {
   color: #000 !important;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.phpbb li.menu-form input.inputbox.search {
   background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/input_search.png");
}
.phpbb li.menu-form input.inputbox.login {
   background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/input_user.png");
}
.phpbb li.menu-form input.inputbox.password {
   background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/input_pass.png");
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to define the fonts? What is the file structure that you are working? There's a lot of css shown, but it seems not related to the question, could you review it and give us better resources to help you?

Comment: I apologize for including all that code, I just wasn't sure what I needed to accomplish this, and I included the code that I knew was related to these images on my site (the menu on the sidebar).

Comment: Hmm. . .guess don't hit enter lol, I'm a newbie here.  Anyway, I'm just trying to swap out the .png images for font icons from a site like this: http://icomoon.io/  I wish I knew what resources you were referencing, I'm just a little short on knowledge at this time, but bear with me, I'm doing my best to learn quickly.  What I incluced were two of the .css files and an html file for the menu.  What in specific could I include to make it easier for someone to spot the part that I need to edit and what files need to be added to use these webfonts?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in some `.css` file might have something defining which `font-family` to use.

You should remove it and add `@font-face` as described here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/